# Power series expansion of a complex function problem

Tags: complex-analysis

I don't know what is the function of the "sup" in $\lim \sup_{n\to \infty} |\beta_n|^{1/n}$ and how to Compute the first three terms
of the Laurent expansion of $1/f (z)$ about $z = 0$

[image: k]

Comment: "lim sup" is a whole, dont try to look for a separate meaning of "lim" and "sup" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_superior_and_limit_inferior). The connection of this expression with the radius of convergence can be found in (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radius_of_convergence)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $2\cosh (z)-1=0\Leftrightarrow z=\pm \dfrac{\pi i}{3}+2\pi ni$, $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

By the root test, $\limsup|\beta_n|^{\frac{1}{n}}=\dfrac{3}{\pi}$. If it took any other value, then the radius of convergence would be different.